# CiviCase - cannot change summary

Tags: civicase

When I try and make changes in the Summary on CiviCase (i.e. change status or type) I get the error message: ***required params missing***.

Any ideas on what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Is it similar to this? [https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35835.msg152247#msg152247](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35835.msg152247#msg152247)

Otherwise need more info, like the log output.

Comment: Pls provide a lot more details. Screenshots would be nice.

Comment: It's nice to be able to answer your own questions. For some reason a number of activities in "case: were not in place and hence the problem. I found the solution, partially by looking at the forum question you referred to, but also by comparing the activity list in the demo version (which was working correctly) with what I had.  Thanks for your pointers.